How to load an isolated JS module in Tauri?
I have a Tauri app (with Vite as the bundler) on which I want to give the users the possible to load small JS scripts. Ideally the user would just declare a index.js and I will just do a folder scan and start from there. This script would ideally load in a web-worker due to the security and isolation guarantees.
I've tried dynamically loading the contents of the script like this:
import { readTextFile } from '@tauri-apps/api/fs';
import { appDataDir } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';

const appDataDirPath = await appDataDir();

const workerScriptPath = `${appDataDirPath}/agents/sample/worker.js`;

const scriptContent = await readTextFile(workerScriptPath);

const blob = new Blob([scriptContent], { type: 'application/javascript' });
const workerUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Create a new Worker
// const worker = new Worker(workerUrl);
const worker = new Worker(workerUrl, { type: 'module' });

worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  logi('Message from worker:', event.data);
};

worker.onerror = (event) => {
  loge('[SIDEBAR]', ` Error in worker: ${event.message}`);
  loge('[SIDEBAR]', JSON.stringify(event));
};

worker.postMessage(
  JSON.stringify({ message: 'Hello from main script!', dataDir: appDataDirPath })
);

This loads the index.js file just fine. The problem is if the file has imports inside, then ofc this does not work since pretty much I'm just passing the contents of the file to the worker object.
// importing directly does not work
// import agentFn from "./index";
// import scripts is also not good as I need to dynamically load from a different disk location
// importScripts("./index.js")

// worker.js in a different location in the file system, not part of the bundler
onmessage = async (event) => {
  const parsedEvent = JSON.parse(event.data);

  // const agent = await import()
  console.log('Message received from main script:');
  console.log(parsedEvent);

  // Trying to load the script dynamically does not work...
  // const agentFn = await import(`${parsedEvent.dataDir}agents/sample/index.js`);
  console.log(agentFn);
  postMessage('Hello, main script!');
};

Is there anyway to achieve this? That is: load an external js file that contains imports into a webview (via Tauri)?
